# AsyncTask to load Activity data, gives NullPointer

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a simple activity with a Navigation drawer I use the following async task to load my Activity data:

```
public void initdata() {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                selfName(); 
                completion();
                getGroupNames();
                imageUri = dbHelper.selfImage(self_name.trim(), self_dob.trim()); 
                percentage = (((6-pages.size())*100)/6);
                return "";

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {


            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);

    }
```

I call this initdata() from my onCreate just after the setContentView(); and later in this function I setup my Nav drawer and pass values calculated in the async task.

I am encountering a weird behavious in which I am getting a Null Pointer exception on one value I pass on to my Nav drawer.

This value is calculated in the completion(); method and set there. The order of my calling hierarchy is:

- onCreate()
- initdata()
- selfName()
- Completion()
- getGroupNames()

The value`percentage = (((6-pages.size())*100)/6);` is caluclated in the initdata() method and I set up my NavDrawer after this call, pass percentage as one argument - I get a nullPointer here. Apparently something is not getting executed in order. If I remove the async task and do all these operations in the onCreate everything works fine. What do I miss here?

Here is the stack trace, the first two lines correspond to System.out messages: The first System.out is carries out from the asynctask (initdata()) the second System.out is carried out just before using the value of `percentage` in the following line:

```
System.out.println("Percentage before navdrawer "+percentage);
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles.get(0).toString(), navMenuIcons[0], true, String.valueOf(percentage)));
```

Trace:

```
04-22 13:25:34.564: I/System.out(2908): Percentage in background: 16
04-22 13:25:34.823: I/System.out(2908): Percentage before navdrawer 16
04-22 13:25:34.823: D/AndroidRuntime(2908): Shutting down VM
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908): Process: com.example, PID: 2908
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at com.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:567)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
04-22 13:25:34.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2908):     ... 10 more
```

The following works:

```
System.out.println("Percentage before navdrawer "+percentage);
System.out.println("Percentage before navdrawer string val"+String.valueOf(percentage));
```

Just before:

```
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles.get(0).toString(), navMenuIcons[0], true, String.valueOf(percentage)));
```

In the above line I get a NPE at `String.valueOf(percentage)`

Comment: Please explain the downvote, I will try to improve this question.

Comment: Done, please have a look!

Comment: what's the content of `MainActivity.java` around the line 567?

Comment: Its the last line of code in my Question `navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles.get(0).toString(), navMenuIcons[0], true, String.valueOf(percentage)));`

Comment: `navMenuTitles.get(0)` is returning null

Comment: I suspect the same, let me try some debugging there.

Comment: The weird part being `navMenuTitles.get(0)` is calculated in the the same asyncttask by calling selfName(), so I am again at square 1.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell you what's going on there without see the code

Comment: The code is huge, I am afraid even if I share it it will be overkill. I will try and debug more.

Comment: please do post all the relevant/dependant parts of the `code`.

Comment: The problem here is that `navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles.get(0).toString(), navMenuIcons[0], true, String.valueOf(percentage)));` is getting called before my initdata() method. Kind of weird when I explictly call initdata() before using `navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles.get(0).toString(), navMenuIcons[0], true, String.valueOf(percentage)));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review the comments, I see:

1) The exception is clear, "navMenuTitles.get(0) is returning null", in your Activity class.

2) The navMenuTitles list is populated in the AsynchTask.

Well it seems that you try access the item 0 before it is populated in your AsyncTask.

It's importante remembered that AsyncTask are executed in a independient Thread.

Comment: I understand, the exception is clear but the order of calling methods is not maintained somehow. My AsyntTask calculates `navMenuTitles.get(0)` However the assignment is executed before calculation, while I am calling the initdata() first and assigning values later.

Comment: Asynch task are executed in a independient Thread. How are you sure that the code "navMenuTitles.get(0).toString()" is executed AFTER the selfName() in your asynchtask?, Maybe I am losing anything.

Comment: That is exactly what is happening!! I think I would have to load data in some intermediate activity. Or else I will have to init my navdrawer in onPostExecute!

Comment: You could move that partial code to onPostExecuteMethod(..), and you would be secured that it goes to be executed after the thread is finish.